# plot chart in chartjs with null points?

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am plotting data using bar in `Chart.js` library . I have to plot data in particular week no. so plotting data with null values at various points. I want to plot [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0KrV.jpg), all the label data and dataset comes in JSON format.

My code is

```
var data = {};
data.WEEKNO = [];
data.accepted = [];
data.planned = [];
data.actual = [];
data.version = [];

$("#rMsg").text("");

var data_ = JSON.parse(retData);
if (Object.keys(data_).length > 0) {

  $("#reW").html("<th>Week No</th>");
  $("#reacp").html("<th>Total Accepted</th>");
  $("#replanned").html("<th>planned</th>");
  $("#react").html("<th>Actual</th>");
  $("#rerev").html("<th>Version</th>");
  for (i in data_.label) { //console.log(data_.label[i]);
    data.WEEKNO.push([i]);
    $("#reW").append("<td>" + [i] + "</td>");

    for (j in data_.requirement) {
      //console.log(j);
      if (data_.label[i] == j) {
        console.log("jjjjj");
        data.accepted.push(data_.requirement[j].accepted);
        data.planned.push(data_.requirement[j].planned);
        data.actual.push(data_.requirement[j].actual);
        data.version.push(data_.requirement[j].version);
        $("#reacp").append("<td>" + data_.requirement[j].accepted + "</td>");
        $("#replanned").append("<td>" + data_.requirement[j].planned + "</td>");
        $("#react").append("<td>" + data_.requirement[j].actual + "</td>");
        $("#rerev").append("<td>" + data_.requirement[j].version + "</td>");
      } else {
        data.accepted.push(null);
        data.planned.push(null);
        data.actual.push(null);
        data.version.push(null);
        $("#reacp").append("<td>" + '' + "</td>");
        $("#replanned").append("<td>" + '' + "</td>");
        $("#react").append("<td>" + '' + "</td>");
        $("#rerev").append("<td>" + '' + "</td>");
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(data.accepted);
  const CHART = document.getElementById("ampleChart");
  var morningChart = new Chart(CHART, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: data.WEEKNO,
      datasets: [{
          label: " accepted",
          data: data.accepted,
          borderColor: "blue",
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          connectNullData: true,
        },
        {
          label: "Plan",
          data: data.planned,
          borderColor: "GREEN",
          backgroundColor: "green",
          connectNullData: true,
        },
        {
          label: "Actual",
          data: data.actual,
          borderColor: "orange",
          backgroundColor: "orange",
          connectNullData: true,
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      spanGaps: true,

      legend: {
        display: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        responsive: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        animationDuration: 2000,
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          align: 'end',
          anchor: 'end',
          color: 'black'
        }
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Percentage'
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          type: "time",
          distribution: 'series',
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              day: 'WW'
            }
          },
          ticks: {
            source: "labels"
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'WEEK NO',
            barThickness: 10
          }
        }],
      }
    }
  });
}
```

my problem is that when I insert two data suppose week 39 data, I don't get chart and in table data move to other places .

JSON format of data looks like this

```
{
  "requirement": {
    "144": {
      "accepted": "879",
      "planned": "",
      "actual": "03",
      "version": ""
    },
    "145": {
      "version": "",
      "accepted": "1189",
      "planned": "",
      "actual": "1154"
    }
  },
  "label": {
    "WW28": "134",
    "WW29": "135",
    "WW30": "136",
    "WW31": "137",
    "WW32": "138",
    "WW33": "139",
    "WW34": "140",
    "WW35": "141",
    "WW36": "142",
    "WW37": "143",
    "WW38": "144",
    "WW39": "145"
  }
}
```

please help me with valuable suggestion